# Django edit the admin template for models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to Django and working on a project.

I have these models

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    applicable_device = models.ManyToManyField(Device)
    applicable_platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Test'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tests'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
    applicable_devices = models.ManyToManyField(Device)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    applicable_events = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    applicable_devices = models.ManyToManyField(Device)
    applicable_platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)

    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    expected_value = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)
```

When I go to the `Event` section in the Django Admin Panel I am able to edit the events. But I want to be able to see a list of all the properties that apply to it underneath where I edit the event.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you have allready done in your admin .py. Did you modify your admin.py file and your form.py ?

form.py

```
from . import models
from django.forms.models import ModelForm
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Event
        fields = ('id','name','test', 'applicable devices')
```

admin.py

`````
from . import models
from . import forms
from django.contrib import admin

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = forms.EventForm
    list_display = ['name','test', 'applicable devices']
# then to register your ModelAdmin
admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
````
`````